# MVC 5 Select List Item with current selection showing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, selectlistitem

My apologies I will not try technical terms to explain my problem, I will try basic English - I want to have my select list to appear in my view with he current selected dealer chosen already (more details below). Thank you in Advance.

I have a product which is stored in its own data table, which is sold by dealers and against the product I store the dealer number who sold it.

I get the dealer number from the dealer data table.

On the web page I create a drop down list when the product is sold which the user selects the dealer name who sold it. I have managed to create the list which shows the names but when selected stores the ID in the product table of the dealer this is working fine.

I am just struggling when I come to edit the product have the select list appear and show the current selected dealer, it always appears with first dealer in the list. I have searched but due to my getting this code fudged together from other SO posts, I can not find a post which works with my code example.

Any feedback/help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Controller

```
            // Create drop down list of dealer names to allow users to select from easily identifiable list rather than find number first before coming to the page.
        var list = db.Dealers.OrderBy(r => r.Name).ToList().Select(rr =>
        new SelectListItem { Value = rr.Name.ToString(), Text = rr.Name }).ToList(); // Require to code and set value based on current selected name.

        ViewBag.DealerName = list;
```

Razor view Code:

```
            <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Dealer_ID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
            <div class="col-md-8">
                @*
                @* Custom display for drop down list which shows Dealer Name instead of numeric ID Value *@
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Dealer_ID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.DealerName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You store `model.Name` to the `Value` of `SelectListItem`, but it should be property that correspond to the value of `model.Dealer_ID`

`rr.ID` or `rr.Dealer_ID`:

```
var list = db.Dealers.OrderBy(r => r.Name).ToList().Select(rr =>
        new SelectListItem { Value = rr.Dealer_ID.ToString(), Text = rr.Name }).ToList();
```

Comment: Hi @Gene R thank you for the prompt reply, unfortunately unless I am understanding your answer incorrectly you may have mis-understood my poorly worded question. My list is working great, but when I go to the page the select list always selects the first dealer in the list. I wish for it to show the currently selected dealer who sold the caravan.

Comment: @AndyDonegan Your list does not contain values for `Dealer_ID` that you bind in your dropdownlist
`Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Dealer_ID...`

Comment: thank you ever so much, I have tried it and tested now and yes you are absolutely correct this now displays the currently selected dealer name. Thanks again for your patience in having to put me right the second time !